# Dynamic xap Loading MVVM Light Apps

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mef, mvvm-light

Hi I'm trying to dynamically load xap files with MEF. I've got some bare bones code working with very basic Silverlight xaps. But loading xaps which are based on MVVM light I get a "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key Locator" which I guess is related to the host need something from MVVM Light. Can anyone with this? Cheers, Chris.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are missing a resource called "Locator", usually being the ViewModelLocator. Look at your view XAML and you should find something like this:

```
<... DataContext="{Binding SomeViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" ...>
```

This line specifies the data context for an element. The data context is bound to the `SomeViewModel` property of a the static resource named `Locator`. Usually the locator is defined in the `App.config` by a statement similar to this:

```
<prefix:ViewModelLocatorClassName x:key="Locator"/>
```

The error most likely means that this line is missing.